# Are unsold goods counted in the national product?

Tags: macroeconomics, accounting

We have this [accounting identity](https://www.albany.edu/%7Ebd445/Economics_301_Intermediate_Macroeconomics_Slides_Spring_2014/National_Income_and_Product.pdf):

`national income = national product`

This make sense to me: CorpA pays \$80 of wages to make a good that sells for \$100 (and is thus is valued at \$100). So workers make \$80, and the company profits \$20, making the national income \$100.

But what if CorpA does not sell what it produces?

My thinking is: CorpA pays \$80 of wages to make a good. The good does not sell. So workers make \$80, CorpA *loses* \$80, so national income is \$0. Therefore national product must be $0. And this unsold good is not counted in the national product (or maybe is valued at \$0?).

Is my thinking correct? Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Since you define national income as being equal to national product you must have the wage of 80. It's not profit, but value of final goods and services. Try to Google GDP unsold products, it will provide lots of detail.

Comment: CorpA now has a good worth \$100.